# Show that there is no nontrivial homomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{x}$

Tags: group-theory

> Show that there is no nontrivial homomorphism between
>
> 1) $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{x}$
>
> 2) $\mathbb{R}^{x}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{x}$
>
> 3) $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{x}$

For 1), I thought of setting $\phi(x_{i})=x_{i}$, then $\phi(x_{1}+x_{2})=x_{1}*x_{2}=x_{1}+x_{2}$. So, the only such map would be the trivial one, right?

For 2), it just seems really obvious that there is no way I can map any of the constants to anything other than identity, so then everything has to be mapped to the identity element. How would I write it mathematically?

Would the argument for 3) be similar to 2)?

Comment: I don't think these claims are obvious...they need proofs.  Can't follow your argument for $1)$.  I think you;ll do better by noting that $\phi(\frac x2)=\sqrt {\phi(x)}$ so if $\phi(x)\neq 1$ we'd have a rational which was neither $0$ nor $1$ but which had a rational square root, fourth root, eighth root, and so on.

Comment: @lulu I was just using the property of the homomorphism that f(xy)=f(x)f(y). And the only such f would be the trivial one then. But yeah I probably didn't do it well

Comment: Well, your $\phi$ doesn't make sense.  The identity isn't even a function here because $\phi(0)$ is undefined.   Anyway, at best all you could show this way is that some particular thing you wrote down wasn't a homomorphism, which wouldn't show that there wasn't one.

Comment: The key word here is divisibility, which is what lulu has alluded to. Both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ are divisible groups, where a group $G$ is divisible if for any $x \in G$, there exists $y \in G$ such that $ny = x$ (I am writing the group operation additively here). See if you can use this idea to figure out what goes wrong if you have a nontrivial homomorphism.

Comment: So, for some $m = na, f(m)=m=f(na)=a^{n}$. And the only such m would be the identity then?

Comment: With ${\Bbb Q}^*$ you mean the multiplicative group?